# Increasing Expression by Comp Index when access CSV File

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm just wondering if someone can help me out. I'm getting error when trying to increase the location of the data in CSV by the composition index.
Here's code I am using
\\

```
var compIndex = parseInt(thisComp.index);
var dataValue = footage("data.csv").dataValue([compIndex - 1, 0]);
dataValue;
```

\\

The reason i'm doing this is to easily duplicate a composition and the expression will grab the data from correct location in CSV file without me going into each composition to increment it manually.